# adding 1 day to a DATETIME format value

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

In certain situations I want to add 1 day to the value of my DATETIME formatted variable:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$_GET['start_hours']}:{$_GET['start_minutes']} {$_GET['start_ampm']}"));
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you want to do this in PHP:

```
// replace time() with the time stamp you want to add one day to
$startDate = time();
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', $startDate));
```

If you want to add the date in MySQL:

```
-- replace CURRENT_DATE with the date you want to add one day to
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: wont this give me the current time? i still need to keep my user inputted time.

Comment: Yes it will but I marked you what values you should change to the custom time. You can just replace `time()` with `strtotime("{$_GET['start_hours']}:{$_GET['start_minutes']} {$_GET['start_ampm']}")`.

Comment: this is not summer-/wintertime save! Please use DST save date/time manipulation

Answer (score 264):

There's more then one way to do this with [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) which was introduced in PHP 5.2. Unlike using `strtotime()` this will account for daylight savings time and leap year.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-29');
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Available in PHP 5.3

$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-29');
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Available in PHP 5.4

echo (new DateTime('2013-01-29'))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Available in PHP 5.5

$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2013-01-29');
$datetime = $start->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Ah, a *loop da loop*.

Comment: If adding more than one day, you can use either plural or singular and get the same result e.g.: `+2 day` or `+2 days` (obviously `+2 days` is more semantically correct)

Comment: What are the practical differences between these methods? The first example seems the simplest and most semantic to me.

Answer (score 38):

The [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) constructor takes a parameter `string time`. `$time` can be different things, it has to respect the [datetime format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

There are some valid values as examples :

- `'now'` (the default value)
- `2017-10-19`
- `2017-10-19 11:59:59`
- `2017-10-19 +1day`

So, in your case you can use the following.

```
$dt = new \DateTime('now +1 day'); //Tomorrow
$dt = new \DateTime('2016-01-01 +1 day'); //2016-01-02
```

Comment: Answering without explanation? Read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 15):

You can use

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date = $now->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Use `strtotime` to convert the string to a time stamp
2. Add a day to it (eg: by adding 86400 seconds (24 * 60 * 60))

eg:

```
$time = strtotime($myInput);
$newTime = $time + 86400;
```

If it's only adding 1 day, then using strtotime again is probably overkill.

Comment: So I need to convert it to a TIMESTAMP then back to a DATETIME format?

Comment: I guess it should also be noted that not every day is 24 hours long. In most places in the world, daylight savings (summer time) means that one day a year is only 23 hours, and one other day is 25 hours.

Comment: Ups. You convert a datetime to a timestamp, so it's UTC based. And _UTC_ days are always 24h long. When converting back with `date()` the local timezone is taken into account which will take care of daylight saving.

Answer (score 7):

You can use as following.

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end_date = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime('+3 days', strtotime($start_date)));
```

You can also set days as constant and use like below.

```
if (!defined('ADD_DAYS')) define('ADD_DAYS','+3 days');
$end_date = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime(ADD_DAYS, strtotime($start_date)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest start using [Zend_Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.basic.html) classes from [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). I know, its a bit offtopic, but I'll like this way :-)

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
$date->add('24:00:00', Zend_Date::TIMES);
print $date->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner !

```
echo (new \DateTime('2016-01-01 +1 day'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using server request time to Add days. Working as expected.

25/08/19 => 27/09/19

```
$timestamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$dateNow = date('d/m/y', $timestamp);
$newDate = date('d/m/y', strtotime('+2 day', $timestamp));
```

Here '+2 days' to add any number of days.