# Add +1 or more day to DATETIME in php eaven if that day is in a different month

Tags: php, date, datetime

I tried the top answer of this question [adding 1 day to a DATETIME format value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286265/adding-1-day-to-a-datetime-format-value) but it didnt work. Im trying to get an easy solution for this: eg: 2017-12-31 +5 day. And I'd like to make a function where i give the current date and the days, or months etc, or if theres a built-in php that can do this, thats eaven better.

Comment: _"it didnt work"_, but what did it actually do?

Comment: Please edit your question to show _how_ you tried it, what input you gave it, what output you expected, and what output you got instead. Without that information, "I tried it but it didn't work" is not useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = "2017-12-31";

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date . " +5 days"));
```

[Strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can translate some sentences to actions. See example 1

Answer (score 0):

here is a alternative function:

```
function get5daysLater($date, $extra_days = 5)
{
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date) +$extra_days *24*60*60);
}
```

Example of use:

```
echo get5daysLater("2017-12-07");
```

Comment: Allthough it will work most of the times, if it's daylight saving you could go short on one hour with this.